# Cannot boot system on real hardware in COSMOS

Tags: c#, boot, bare-metal, cosmos

I have recently made a C# Cosmos system. It is very simple, with a few commands. I can run this on VMware without any problems, but when I flash the ISO onto a USB stick with RUFUS and then boot it from my HP-Pavillion-360-Convertable with 4GB of RAM, this is the error I get:

[image: The Error]

Edit(Suggested by Dijkgraaf):

Here is the error in text:

```
Finding PCI Devicesd
Starting ACPI
Searching Ethernet Controllers...
Found Unknown device on PCI 2:0:0
No supported network card found!!
Exception occurred while running kernel:
Exception: No disks found!
```

Is there any way I can fix this? If so, how?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the error message as text.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on their discord or github discussions page https://www.gocosmos.org/?

Comment: how do you make your OS bootable with rufus? because when I trying to make my OS bootable with rufus, I've got an error says "non-bootable image is not supported by rufus"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that VFS sucks and will not work on modern disks like SATA, etc... it only works on IDE. So, I removed VFS and it booted with RUFUS with a FAT32 filesystem.

*Thanks to the discord server for helping me out!*

Comment: If your problem is solved then please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @RBT There is a 48 hour delay before you can accept your own answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer